# Ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook Air Mid-2011 Graphic Issue

Tags: 20.04, firefox, macbook-air

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a MacBook Air mid-2011 and Ubuntu works great. But I have a graphic issue with Firefox. I don't know how and when it happens but everyday I'm having this issue. Icons disappear, fonts get crappy. Restarting Firefox solves the problem. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Ubuntu or Firefox, so I'm posting the issue here.

[image: screenshot]

Edit 1: I installed MX Linux 19.2 on the same machine and I didn't have any issues with it.

Edit 2: I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my 27 inch iMac 2010 and there is no issue there.

```
lspci -nn |grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

**iMac**

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Broadway PRO [Mobility Radeon HD 5850] [1002:68a1]

**MacBook Air**

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

Comment: Are you running under wayland?

Comment: I spent three weeks trying to fix this problem but unfortunately I gave up and went back to High Sierra. I wish I could stay on Ubuntu because I liked it very much. Maybe next time :(